# Trouble with network (ping, route, gateway)

Tags: linux-networking, ethernet, centos7

I have a server running CentOS 7 and I connect to it by ssh.  SSH takes a little bit to connect compared to the other server I have setup.  This server has 2 ethernet ports (1 motherboard and 1 card).  I use the card to create a bridge network for Kvm virtual machines and it works fine.  There are times I can't ping or if I use the route command it hangs.  I think it has to do with the default gateway for the main ethernet port.

Route when having issues

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.1.1.3        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 br0
10.1.1.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 em1
10.1.1.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 em1
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
```

then I run sudo route add default gw 10.1.1.3 em1 or sudo route add default gw 10.1.1.3

```
route

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.1.1.3        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 em1
default         10.1.1.3        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 br0
10.1.1.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 em1
10.1.1.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 em1
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
```

I have added the default gateway to the /etc/sysconfig/network file, but still have issues.

```
sudo cat /etc/sysconfig/network

# Created by anaconda
GATEWAY=10.1.1.3
```

Any ideas?

Thanks for the help.

P.S. I know that they should be static ip addresses and I'm working on it, but having to wait on the net admin.

UPDATE:

I added the GATEWAYDEV=em1 to /etc/sysconfig/network file and restarted network services.  I ran route and this is the output.

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.1.1.3        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 em1
10.1.1.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 em1
10.1.1.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 em1
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1004   0        0 br0
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
```

I connected to the virtual machines by ssh and pinged google and they returned results so it seems to work.  Though I wondering if the bridge network will be fine since the default line isn't there any more for the br0 interface?

Update 2:

I commented out the gatewaydev and added gateway to the ifcfig-em1 file and restarted the network, but route hanged and gave the first results in the post.  So I remove gateway from ifcfg-em1 and uncommented the gatewaydev and restarted the network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to set GATEWAY in your ethernet file not in /etc/sysconfig/network

`[root@puppetmaster]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens33`
`TYPE=Ethernet`
`BOOTPROTO=static`
`DEFROUTE=yes`
`PEERDNS=yes`
`PEERROUTES=yes`
`IPADDR=192.168.1.10`
`SUBNETMASK=255.255.255.0`
`GATEWAY=192.168.1.1`

Comment: /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-em1 that the file I believe

Comment: Add GATEWAYDEV=em1 in  /etc/sysconfig/network , this also works when you have multiple interface.

Comment: I will give both ways a try.  Thanks for the help.